# imapclient.IMAPClient [Seen] Flag in Python

Tags: imap, flags, imapclient

I am processing emails using imapclient.IMAPClient in Python and want to flag the successfully processed emails as "Seen" at the end. I have tried different ways but they either do not flag all the successful email or do not show as "read" in my Gmail inbox. I am looking for a way to update Gmail inbox flags of successfully processed emails using IMAP.

Here is the summary of code that I've tried:

```
imapObj = imapclient.IMAPClient(self.server_host, ssl=True)
imapObj.login(self.user_name, self.password)
imapObj.select_folder(email_folder, readonly=False)
#searches unseen emails with subject containing document
self.emails = imapObj.search(
        [search_criterion1, search_value1,
        search_criterion2, search_value2,
        search_criterion3, search_value3,
        search_flag])

#using PEEK to not mark all the emails as [Seen]
self.raw_messages = imapObj.fetch(self.emails, 'BODY.PEEK[]')
self.successful_emails = []
for i, self.email_id in enumerate(self.emails):

...do some process and for each successful process, append the email_id to list...
    self.successful_emails.append(self.email_id)

#flag the successfully processed email as [SEEN] 
imapObj.set_flags(self.successful_emails, '+FLAGS', '\SEEN')
```

Comment: Please provide some code that you've tried.  Also note that of you set the \Seen flag via IMAP, it will take some time for the web front end to reload and see it, especially if you already have it open

Comment: @Max Thanks, I have just added code details to my post.